# Apache Tomcat 7.0.37 SSL Error (ssl_error_rx_record_too_long firefox or

Tags: tomcat, ssl, wildcard

I don't know what the problem is. I'm using a wildcard SSL cert that was installed on another server using tomcat. I copied the Keystore and associated files to the new server and made the same config to the server.xml file as I used on the initial server:

```
--><Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="C:\\JDK\bin\tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="*****" />
```

Just to document, we're tomcat is by default using port 8080, so we're trying https://x.x.x.x:8080

In the tomcat\logs folders, I've seen no error message that talks directly to the issue when making connection attempts from within the network or outside of our network using NAT. The only log file updated during attempts is the "localhost_access_log.2013-10-29.txt" and inside there is just says:
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [29/Oct/2013:11:21:58 -0700] " Ï  ËRoüÆÛYoX®¡' ¨?V¬µÕMúÆS|C  (À " 400 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [29/Oct/2013:11:19:16 -0700] "-" 400 -

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using https://x.x.x.x:8443 so you hit the HTTPS connector rather than the HTTP connector.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with apache-tomcat-7.0.53, looking at [SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration), i find that tomcat 7 requires the SSLEnabled of the connector tag to be set to true, in order to enable SSL.

Another one thing is that i'm using the protocol "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" the exact configuration details depend on which implementation of SSL (APR or JSSE) is being used.

Best Regards.